# PHP strip_tags() causing problems with line break-converter?

Tags: php, line-breaks, strip-tags

Im building a public forum from scratch, and im fine tuning, and testing everything now. Im currently stuck at the function that strips all html tags expect those i use for insering youtube-videoes, and bold/italic tags so that the user atleast has some way of styling their posts. My problem, is that when i use the nl2br2() function for filtering my post-string, it dosnt strip the html-tags from the string, it works fine if i remove nl2br2() ..? My theory is that the strip_tags() function also strips the native system line breaks \n and \r, so that nl2br2() haven't got any line break to convert. Im actually pretty sure, that's the problem! How can i make those two functions work together? Is there any alternatives to strip_tags()? Or can you somehow tell the function, to stop stripping those linebreaks!!? Its really annoying, been spending lots of hours today trying to figure this out :D any help is much apreaciated!

**THIS DIDN'T WORKD:**

```
function nl2br2($string) { 
   $string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $string); 
   return $string; 
} 


        $str = "$_POST[indlaeg]";
        mysql_real_escape_string($str); // PROTECT FROM SQL INJECTIONS THROUGH SINGLE QUOTES ''
        strip_tags($str, '<b><i><a><video><br>'); // REMOVE ALL TAGS EXPECT
        $str = nl2br2($str); // CONVERT LINE BREAKS TO <br>
```

**THIS DIDN'T WORK EITHER:**

```
$str = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(nl2br2($_POST['indlaeg']), '<b><i><a><video><br>'));
```

**THIS WORKED!!!!**

```
  function html2txt($document){ 
  $search = array('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',  // Strip out javascript 
           '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',            // Strip out HTML tags 
           '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly 
           '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'         // Strip multi-line comments including     CDATA ); 
  $text = preg_replace($search, '', $document); 
  return $text; 
  }

$str = "$_POST[indlaeg]";
$str = html2txt($str);
$str = nl2br2($str);
```

The html2txt() function is sent from heaven! It strips ALL evil-minded tags! Including the single quotes '' that hackers like to use for SQL injection :D

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

Comment: Learn [PHP the right way](http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases) and get rid of `mysql_*`.

Comment: You’ve missed the closing parenthesis and semicolon for your array of regular expressions.

Comment: Does the function `html2txt` preserve the following tags: `<b><i><a><video><br>` and delete all others? It was one of your initial requirements.

Comment: True! But after so many hours of not getting both line-breaks and strip-html-tags to work at the same time. I made up my mind, that security was my top priority, and i get that with this solution i feel :) Then ofcourse i have to made five str_replace() lines AFTER html2txt() .. for my five permitted tags, best solution i could come up with, and at the end of the day, i can sleep at night knowing that my forum is protected from attacks, while getting my smiley, line-break replacements done :D

Comment: @ user555 read my updated solution, im not using mysql_real_escape_string() anymore ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re applying three functions to your string – `mysql_real_escape_string`, `strip_tags` and `nl2br2`. The order should be reversed because `mysql_real_escape_string` adds a backslash before `\n` and `\r`, making the string unable to be processed by `nl2br2`. If you apply `nl2br2` first, `strip_tags` next and `mysql_real_escape_string` last, no such problems should arise.

Replace these four lines

```
$str = "$_POST[indlaeg]";
mysql_real_escape_string($str); // PROTECT FROM SQL INJECTIONS THROUGH SINGLE QUOTES ''
strip_tags($str, '<b><i><a><video><br>'); // REMOVE ALL TAGS EXPECT
$str = nl2br2($str); // CONVERT LINE BREAKS TO <br>
```

with

```
$str = $_POST['indlaeg'];
$str = nl2br2($str); // CONVERT LINE BREAKS TO <br>
$str = strip_tags($str, '<b><i><a><video><br>'); // REMOVE ALL TAGS EXCEPT A FEW
$str = mysql_real_escape_string($str); // PROTECT FROM SQL INJECTIONS THROUGH SINGLE QUOTES ''
```

Comment: ive tried that thousands of times now! The big mystery is that when i do this, the strip_tags() function dosnt strip ANY tags? :S thanks for input though!

Comment: Ok, now it strips the html tags. But now it wont register line breaks! *banging head against the wall*

Comment: Your head is not at fault! Please stop doing such irremediable harm to it! See my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, just an expression of how frustrating coding can be sometimes :P Creative mashup of so many functions in one line! Thought it would work just from looks of it dude, PROPS! :D But sadly, didnt make difference.. Read on php.net that strip_tags actually strips all line breaks AND whitespaces! What a stupid function, considering  what most people use it for.. Guess the developers didnt think about, that we need the native linebreak symbols from ALL textareas LOL ;) Found a way, to avoid this function and every works smoothly now!! Will post my solution in a few minutes, stay tuned!

Comment: Thank you very much for accepting my answer even though it didn’t solve your problem. Anyway, [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags) removes neither line breaks nor whitespaces. You may test it with `var_dump(strip_tags(" \r\n"));`. Which line(s) in the PHP manual is/are responsible for this misunderstanding?

Comment: Here's a quote from the top if the page.. "allowable_tags - 
This parameter should not contain whitespace.
HTML comments and PHP tags are also stripped. This is hardcoded and can not be changed with allowable_tags." in other words, <br> can't be an exception..